# Where can I find the source code for ProfileSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, profiler

I want to read the source code of ProfileSharp, a free and open source .NET profiler written in C#. All my searches lead either to source forge or some Indian consulting company's home page.

I do not see any page that hosts the source code for this software. What happened to ProfileSharp? Does anyone have a link to its source code?

Comment: may it help https://github.com/Bathla/ProfileSharp

Comment: Thanks very much, Aaron. Do you also know where I can find the source code for NProfiler? I can't seem to open this Web page: http://chimpswithkeyboards.com/projects/nprofiler/